# View to replace values with max value corresponding to a match

Tags: sql, view

I am sure my question is very simple for some, but I cannot figure it out and it is one of those things difficult to search an answer for. I hope you can help.

In a table in SQL I have the following (simplified data):

```
UserID   UserIDX   Number   Date
aaa      bbb       1        21.01.2000
aaa      bbb       5        21.01.2010
ppp      ggg       9        21.01.2009
ppp      ggg       3        15.02.2020
xxx      bbb       99       15.02.2020
```

And I need a view which will give me the same amount of records, but for every combination of UserID and UserIDX, there should be only 1 value under the Number field, i.e. the highest value found in the combination data set. The Date field needs to remain unchanged. So the above would be transformed to:

```
UserID   UserIDX   Number   Date
aaa      bbb       5        21.01.2000
aaa      bbb       5        21.01.2010
ppp      ggg       9        21.01.2009
ppp      ggg       9        15.02.2020
xxx      bbb       99       15.02.2020
```

So, for all instances of aaa+bbb combination the unique value in Number should be 5 and for ppp+ggg the unique number is 9.

Thank you very much.

Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select userid,useridx,maxnum,date
from table a
inner join (
    select userid,useridx,max(number) maxnum
    from table
    group by userid,useridx) b
 on a.userid = b.userid and a.useridx = b.useridx
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Derek. I have replaced "table" in your code with my actual table but I am getting "Ambiguous column name 'userid'" (and the same for useridx) in line 1. Any ideas? I can confirm that these are indeed fields of my table...

Comment: @user1266732 you need to specify which table the userid is coming from in your SELECT area.  It needs to be a.userid or b.userid, it needs to  start with your table alias.

Comment: Great, thank you Derek and bluefeet for the clarification. PS: I tried to vote up the answer but it wont let me as I dont have 15 reputation points. This is my first post here...

Comment: @user1266732 if you cannot upvote yet, when you get the rep you can come back but remember to accept this as the answer.